# Could not load file or assembly 'idrsnet15.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll

I'm trying to add third party C# dll as resource in my Asp.net WebService Project with these configurations.

C# DLL build in dotnet framework 4 in x64 environment with Runtime version(4.0.30319).
We are using VS 2010 framework version 4.0.30319 RTMRel; under ASP.Net webservice project configuration we set target framework 4 with target x64 Platform.

I need to use this DLL into my web service application but getting run time exceptions while browsing it through IIS.

----------------------------ERROR DETAIL------------------------------------------------------------

> Could not load file or assembly 'idrsnet15.dll' or one of its
>   dependencies. The specified module could not be found.    Description:
>   An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'idrsnet15.dll' or one of its dependencies. The
>   specified module could not be found.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'idrsnet15.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could
>   not be found.]
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark,
>   Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +567
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +192    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +35
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +118
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'idrsnet15.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could
>   not be found.]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +11392147
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +484    System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal() +127    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +334
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +280
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1087
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'idrsnet15.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could
>   not be found.]    System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +11524352
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +141    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +4782309
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1 
>   ----------------------------ERROR DETAIL------------------------------------------------------------

We created Asp.net project by selecting 3.5 framework then set target framework 4.0 under application configuration.

I can witness TempAsp.net files including assembly and third party dll under this path:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\myocrapp\f4fd840d\f71f8f0e\assembly\dl3\1a6aa3d5\00bb235d_957bcf01

Comment: Please, consider changing the name of the post to something easier for the users, as explained in the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Ashok for the contribution.

We resolved this exception by configuring 'PATH' environment variable with the value of IDRS un-managed dlls(the path where other IDRS un-managed dll reside) because when IIS deploy the application it only deploy managed dll to the temporary folder but remaining un-managed third party dll still needed to load successfully.

Comment: Did you set the Path environment variable on the publishing machine? I have native C++ dlls (unmanaged) and I get the same error when publishing. Do the dlls have to be published for the app to find them, or can you just upload them to the bin folder?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, first of all Check have you included your third party dll referene  properly(does exist in publish folder or virtual directory) 
second thing have you provided  IIS to enough access permission for accessing your third party dll , so for that you can set your IIS virtual directory to have access to IIS user acccount.

You can use Dependency Walker as well to come to know dependent assemblies required for your Third party dll (http://dependencywalker.com/) and all the required files are present in your system, also check for version related information of your 3rd party dll (as X64 and x86 are different and may be not loaded in some conditions).